# Proof involving fractions

Tags: alternative-proof, fractions

> A stick is divided by red marks into 7 equal segments and by green marks into 13 equal segments. Then it is cut into 20 equal pieces. Prove that any piece (except the 2 end pieces) contain exactly one mark (which may be green or red)

My textbook previously introduces the concept of the mediant of 2 fractions and uses it to prove as follows:$$\text{every red mark is of the form }\frac{x}{7}$$ $$\text{every green mark is of the form }\frac{y}{13}$$ $$\operatorname{mediant}\left(\frac{x}{7},\frac{y}{13}\right) = \frac{x+y}{20}$$
***so between any 2 green and red segments, there is a cut point and therefore, 2 segments of different colour cannot belong to the same piece.***

***Moreover, 2 segments of the same colour cannot belong to the same piece as both $\frac{1}{7}\text{   }$&$\text{   }\frac{1}{13}$ are greater than $\frac{1}{20}$***

However, I want to know if there is another, simpler proof that does not require any knowledge of the mediant, especially if the denominator of the cut points is not equal to the sum of the denominators of the marks

Comment: I think the proof , and the mediant idea, works precisely because $20$ is the sum. Change $20$ to say $22$ pieces, and not every piece will have a mark of some colour. Change $20$ to say $18$ pieces, and one of them will have marks of two different colours. So $20$ is chosen very carefully to fit the mediant idea in.

Comment: How would you then disprove the statement for 22 or 18? By exhaustion or is there a (relatively) easier way?

Comment: I wanted to insert space between the characters and didn't realise I could just put the entire sentence in \text( ). As you can see, I'm not very bright..... Really sorry about that

Comment: You don't need `\text{ }` to put space between symbols in a math formula. Just use`\ ` (a blank after the backward slash). For smaller or larger amounts of space, `\,` or `\;` or `\quad` or `\qquad` and possibly others I've overlooked. But of course using `\text{}` to contain _the actual text parts of the formula_ is the best practice.

Comment: One proof is dumb brute-force computation.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon : There are not $20$ marks; there are $18{:}$ $$ \left\{ \tfrac 1 7, \ldots,\tfrac 6 7 \right\} \cup \left\{ \tfrac 1 {13}, \ldots,\tfrac{12}{13}  \right\}. $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry, good point. However, I forgot to mention that OP neglected the parts of the stick containing the end points, so that makes $18$ marks for $18$ parts in the question. The arguments I made earlier would still go through e.g. for a stick cut into $22$ parts, $20$ parts not containing an end cannot each contain a coloured mark if there are only $18$, similarly for a stick cut into $18$ parts, there must be one part not containing an endpoint that contains at least two marks of different colours.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the stick is $20(13)(7)$ long
We have 20 pieces of length $13(7)$ with places {0,1,2,3,...,19}
And 13 red pieces of length $20(7)$
And 7 green pieces  of length $20(13)$

The first red will be on place 1 $(20=1(13)+7)$the second red will be on place 3 $(40=3(13)+1$ the third red will be on place 4 $floor(60/13)=4$
In general the $n$ red mark will be on the $[20(n)/13]$ place

For the green the $m$ green mark will be on the $[20(m)/7]$

Now you need to show the for $n=1\cdots 13$ and $m=1\cdots 7$

$$\left[\frac{20(n)}{13}\right]\ne \left[\frac{20(m)}{7}\right]$$